# IPTV malfunctioning when my bridged connection is active

Tags: wireless-networking, connection, iptv, bridged

I am using an ADSL connection, and i have set up a bridged connection in my room, because the main receiver/router is in the living room and the wireless signal is weak. When the router in my room is on, the problem occurs, the TV pictures get still on both TVs, in the living room and in my room, and when i plug off my router, everything goes back to normal.

Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You do not say if the "bridged connection in your room" is Ethernet or WiFi. I will assume WiFi.

In most cases commercial IPTV is multicast to the end-user. If any of your equipment (switches and routers) is not multicast aware, that device is likely to flood the IPTV packets out all connected ports.

Without more information I am not able to offer a solution, other than looking at getting a UTP cable between your bridge and router. WiFi is not a great transport for IPTV, unless you are able to do some serious tweaking to it. Have a look in the advanced menus of both devices and see if they have any Multimedia settings.